# How to convert a string to "System.Windows.Forms.TabPage"?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to remove TabPages of a tabControle in a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    var tabPage = "tabPage" + i;
    tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage); // converting error here
}
```

how can I convert the string to the TabPage object?

thx

Comment: Well what exactly does `tabPage` relate to? The ID of the `TabPage` you want to remove? It's name? It's text? What exactly does it refer to?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all pages **except the first one**, you cannot use a loop in that way.

When you remove an element from the collection your index will be out of sync with the total number of elements in the collection and you risk to get an *Index out of range exception* and still you haven't removed all of the intedend page because the position of the remaining pages shifts while you remove elements in the collection.

The usual trick is to loop in reverse order

```
for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
{
    tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(i); 
}
```

In alternative, if your string represents the property Key of the tabPage, you could use [RemoveByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.removebykey.aspx)

```
for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
{
    var tabPageKey = "tabPage" + i;
    tabControl.TabPages.RemoveByKey(tabPageKey); 
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned on p.s.w.g's answer, you can't just assume the tabs are named in the actual order they're stored in the TabPages Collection. A tab's name and its position in the list may be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    var tabPage = FindControl("tabPage" + i);
    tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage); 
}
```

Or this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    var tabPage = "tabPage" + i;
    tabControl.TabPages.RemoveByKey(tabPage); 
}
```

Or this to remove the first 6 tab pages:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) 
{
    tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(0); 
}
```

Or if the goal is to remove *all* the tab pages, this is much easier:

```
tabControl.TabPages.Clear();
```

Comment: The third loop works best. The second one is actually kind of dangerous, though: just because a tab is named "tabPage3" doesn't mean it's the 4th one in the collection.

Also, like Steve mentioned, if you're going to remove by index, you need to either do so in reverse order or always call TabPages.RemoveAt(0).

Comment: @Cobra That's true, I've included a note to indicate that the behavior of the `RemoveAt` loop will not be identical to the others